# Is "Dot Pitch" the distance between like-colored LEDs?

Tags: display, lcd, terminology, led, pixels

My understanding is that LEDs provide backlight in LED displays, while dot pitch is the **distance between subpixels on the screen**——these two are completely different concepts. 
But according to *New Perspectives on Computer Concepts 2018*, Dot Pitch is the **distance between two LEDs of the same color**. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: LEDs [sometimes] provide backlight in L**C**D displays

Comment: Yes it does, but aren't pixels and LEDs placed on two seperate layers?

Comment: Dot pitch is the distance between adjacent pixel centers, and not *"subpixels'*.  For an RGB display, the center of the pixels could be equivalent to just using the subpixels of the same color.  The text seems wrong; that definition would only apply to a (real) LED display (e.g. OLED display), and not apply to LCD and LCD w/LED backlighting (aka misnamed *"LED"* display, and only have white LEDs).